# Cypress doubleclick or click + enter action do not trigger DOM change as expected

Tags: cypress

I have to enter a value in an input that only appears in the DOM on a double click. However, I have tried double clicking, clicking and typing enter, most of the time it fails (it seems to double click but then gets back out of it instead of staying in the state of picture #2, so the input is not present and I can not enter that new value.

Before double clicking

```
<div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="4" comp-id="331" col-id="averageRate" class="ag-cell ag-cell-auto-height ag-right-aligned-cell ag-cell-value ag-cell-focus ag-cell-not-inline-editing" style="width: 168px; left: 504px;">
   <msc-basic-cell-renderer _nghost-mnn-c205="">
     <div _ngcontent-mnn-c205="" class="cell-renderer-wrapper">
       <span _ngcontent-mnn-c205=""> 0.799387 </span>
       <!----><!----><!---->
     </div>
  </msc-basic-cell-renderer>
</div>
```

After manually double clicking (or clicking + enter key)

```
<div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="4" comp-id="331" col-id="averageRate" class="ag-cell ag-cell-auto-height ag-right-aligned-cell ag-cell-value ag-cell-focus ag-column-hover ag-cell-inline-editing" style="width: 168px; left: 504px;">
   <msc-numeric-input _nghost-mnn-c217="">
       <div _ngcontent-mnn-c217="" class="numeric-cell msc-h100 w-100 ng-touched ng-pristine ng-valid">
          <input _ngcontent-mnn-c217="" type="number" placeholder="Value" class="numeric-input msc-h100 w-100 ng-touched ng-pristine ng-valid focus-visible" data-focus-visible-added="">
       </div><!----> 
    </msc-numeric-input>
</div>
```

**Before**
[image: before]

**After**
[image: after]

Here is the code that works most of the time. I had to add hard coded waits and bypass the linting rules:

```
cy.wait(5000);

cy.get(`.mfc-dialog-overlay div[ref="eCenterContainer"] div[col-id="${field}"]`).click();
cy.wait(1000);
cy.get('.mfc-dialog-overlay div[ref="eCenterContainer"] div.ag-cell-focus')
      .as('cell').type('1');
cy.wait(1000);
cy.get('@cell').invoke('html').then(innerHtml => {
      if (innerHtml.includes('msc-basic-cell-renderer')) {
              cy.wait(1000);
              cy.get('@cell').type('1');
        }
});
cy.wait(1000).get(`msc-numeric-input input`, { timeout: 5000 }).type(value);
cy.get(this.HEADER_ON_RATES_POPOVER).click();
```

I also tried dblclick({force: true}), click() and then type('{enter}') to no avail... it's at best intermittently working while not working most of the time.

Comment: please share the code that you tried ?

Comment: Please add your cypress code, and we will do our best

Comment: Here is the code that works most of the time. I had to add hard coded waits and bypass the linting rules:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the images, you have an **ag-grid** which can be slow and require extra timeout options on commands (rather than fixed `cy.wait()` calls).

There's a pair of classes `ag-cell-not-inline-editing` and `ag-cell-inline-editing` that coincide with the two cell states shown in your images.

These are useful to ensure you have the correct state.

**Simplest test with vanilla ag-grid**

```js
cy.get('[row-id="0"]', {timeout: 10000}).within(() => {    // first row

  const field = 'lastName'

  cy.get(`div[col-id="${field}"]`)
    .should('have.class', 'ag-cell-not-inline-editing')  // confirm not editing
  
  cy.get(`div[col-id="${field}"]`)
    .type('Johnson')                                // .type() automatically gives focus
    .should('have.class', 'ag-cell-inline-editing') // confirm entered editing state

  cy.get(`div[col-id="${field}"]`)
    .type('{enter}')                         // close editing state

  cy.get(`div[col-id="${field}"]`)
    .should('have.class', 'ag-cell-not-inline-editing')  // confirm not editing
    .and('have.text', 'Johnson')                       // confirm text
})
```

---

There's an extra layer in the cells (`<msc-numeric-input>`) which may be causing your timing issues. I can't identify it to test directly, but may be a webAssembly component.

In any case, the timing can be resolved by waiting for the input to appear (which you seem to have already identified)

**Waiting for `<input>`**

```js
cy.get('[row-id="0"]', {timeout: 10000}).within(() => {

  const field = 'lastName'

  cy.get(`div[col-id="${field}"]`)
    .should('have.class', 'ag-cell-not-inline-editing')

  cy.get(`div[col-id="${field}"]`)
    .dblclick()                                      // trigger editing mode
    .should('have.class', 'ag-cell-inline-editing')  // confirm editing mode
    .find('input', {timeout: 10000})                 // confirm input appears
    .type('Johnson')

  cy.get(`div[col-id="${field}"]`)
    .type('{enter}')                                // exit editing mode

  cy.get(`div[col-id="${field}"]`)
    .should('have.class', 'ag-cell-not-inline-editing')
    .and('have.text', 'Johnson')

})
```

---

Can also exit editing mode by clicking away from the cell, e.g

```js
cy.get(`div[col-id="${field}"]`)       // exit editing mode
  .next().click()                      // instead of .type('{enter}')
```

or tabbing (which automatically enter editing on next cell)

```js
cy.get(`div[col-id="${field}"]`)       // exit editing mode
  .trigger('keydown', { keyCode: 9 })  // instead of .type('{enter}')
```

Comment: This looks amazing. Will try this out next week and let you know how it went! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This looks like it should work, but unfortunately it doesn't. Even with adding a 5 seconds wait before to make sure the modal is fully loaded, what doesn't work is getting that div to get to the editing stage. Tried dblclick and type and nothing seems to get that input to appear programmatically. It just clicks in and out immediately when I watch it but doesn't stay in the editing mode.